# Sticky footer with a site-long container

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I'm terribly sorry but I've been 'having fun' with lots of random sticky footer solutions for 2 days and I'm slowly starting to ponder suicide.
Alright! So I'm aware of this solution: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ but I don't know how to make it work with another container that contains the footer.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.content {
  background-color: #C33C54;
}
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer,
.push {
  height: 4em;
}
.footer {
  background-color: #254E70;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css" ... />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>HEADER</header>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Your website content here.
          <p>
      </div>
      <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <p>Copyright (c)</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help? It's the only thing left in my design and I gotta get in done today. Thank you!

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xOwBBN

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your container 100% height too.

```
html,
body,
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```